# In VBA, is it possible to detect the "Ctrl" key being pressed and the mouse wheel being scrolled at the same time?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I"m interested in implementing a form-zoom function in Access VBA using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and a mouse scroll event. If the user holds the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and scrolls up, the form zooms in. If the user holds the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and scrolls down, the form zooms out.

I know how to capture a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key press and I know how to detect a mouse scroll event, but I don't know how to do both at the same time. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it. I create a boolean variable outside the functions definitions to know when the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is being pressed.

```
Private ctrlKeyIsPressed As Boolean
```

and then I change that variable to `True` or `False` in the `KeyDown` event:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    'Detect if the "Ctrl" key was pressed
    If (Shift And acCtrlMask) > 0 Then
        ctrlKeyIsPressed = True
    End If

End Sub
```

**Update:**

You also need to use the KeyUp event for the form to set the `ctrlKeyIsPressed` is pressed variable to false.

```
Private Sub Form_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    ctrlKeyIsPressed = False
End Sub
```

Then in the mouse wheel event, I use that variable:

```
Private Sub Form_MouseWheel(ByVal Page As Boolean, ByVal Count As Long)

    'If the "Ctrl" key is also being pressed, then zoom the form in or out
    If ctrlKeyIsPressed Then

        If Count < 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Zoom In"
        ElseIf Count > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Zoom Out"
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```